# Блокировка потока (Thread) при вызове методов read() или write() классов Java IO

Tags: java, многопоточность, io

Ниже цитаты из статьи с Хабра. [ссылка на статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/235585/)

Я выделил ту часть, по которой есть вопросы.

> Потоки ввода/вывода (streams) в Java IO являются блокирующими. Это значит, что когда в потоке выполнения (thread) вызывается `read()` или `write()` метод любого класса из пакета `java.io.*`, **происходит блокировка до тех пор, пока данные не будут считаны или записаны. Поток выполнения в данный момент не может делать ничего другого.**

Вопрос:

1. А разве может этот текущий поток (thread) делать в момент выполнения метода `read()` или `write()`, что-то кроме самого выполнения метода `read()` или `write()` даже если бы блокировки потока не происходило? Я имею в виду, если у нас например, идёт последовательный вызов методов `a()`, `read()`, `b()` , то разве может произойти вызов метода `b()` раньше, чем завершится выполнение метода `read()`? Я подумал может в тексте опечатка и имеется в виду, что **процесс** *не может делать ничего другого*... то есть при блокировке текущего потока, при наличии других потоков в **процессе**, управление перешло бы к ним (и тогда бы например, программа могла бы выполнять параллельно другие задачи или просто была отзывчива к действиям пользователя и т.д.). Но в цитате сказано про текущий поток и ни слова про другие. Объясните пожалуйста, чего я не понимаю.

Далее вырезка с цитатой из книги Кея Хорстманна, где я выделил интересующий меня момент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь автор также говорит про блокировку потока (thread), в случае вызова методов `read()` и `write()`, но в контексте существования других потоков сам факт наличия такой блокировки - это плюс (если я правильно понял), так как управление может передаться другим потокам (thread). Но потом он приводит пример кода, который по его словам даёт возможность избежать блокировки при вызове метода `read()` и в связи с этим вопросы:

1. Зачем может понадобиться выполнять такую проверку, чтобы избежать блокировки потока, ведь так управление другим потокам не передастся? В каких ситуациях это может понадобиться?
2. Правильно ли  понимаю, что использование метода `available()` **нужно как раз для таких ситуаций**, когда есть несколько потоков и мы по какой-то причине не хотим передавать управление другим потокам, в случае чтения данных в текущем потоке, то есть хотим избежать блокировки текущего потока?

Заранее благодарю всех за подробные ответы!

Answer (score 1):

В той же статье, что вы представили по ссылке есть замечательная аналогия:

> Чтобы лучше понять концепцию и выгоду от применения селекторов, давайте абстрагируемся от программирования и представим себе железнодорожный вокзал. Вариант без селектора: есть три железнодорожных пути (каналы), на каждый из них в любой момент времени может прибыть поезд (данные из буфера), на каждом пути постоянно ожидает сотрудник вокзала (поток выполнения), задача которого – обслуживание прибывшего поезда. В результате трое сотрудников постоянно находятся на вокзале даже если там вообще нет поездов. Вариант с селектором: ситуация та же, но для каждой платформы есть индикатор, сигнализирующий сотруднику вокзала (поток выполнения) о прибытии поезда. Таким образом на вокзале достаточно присутствия одного сотрудника.

Таким образом саму концепцию блокирования/неблокирования нужно рассматривать именно с этой стороны.

Отвечаю на ваши вопросы:

Нет, поток(thread) не может выполнять какой-то другой метод в момент выполнения текущего. То есть, если у вас последовательный вызов методов `a()` -> `read()` -> `b()`, то в момент выполнения метода `read()` он не может выполнять никакой другой метод, независимо от того, есть блокировка или нет. И последовательность вызовов тоже сохраняется (я не беру в рассмотрение [reordering](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#reordering)).
Здесь нужно рассматривать блокировку потока(thread) не с той точки зрения, что поток(thread) переходит в какое-то другое состояние (`BLOCKED/WAITING`), а с той, что он не сможет продвинуться дальше на метод `b()` до тех пор, пока не прочитает данные из входного потока. Он повторяет попытку чтения в бесконечном цикле, пока не дойдёт до конца. В этом и смысл блокировки, что у вас на пути всегда стоит работник вокзала и ожидает, пока придёт поезд, чтобы его обслужить. Хотя в это время он мог бы заниматься какими-то полезными делами.
Причины, по которым во входном потоке нет данных, могут быть различны (нагрузка на сеть, ожидание данных от другого приложения и так далее), поэтому гораздо эффективнее, когда у вас поток(thread) в этот момент занимается какой-то полезной работой и лишь изредка выходит на перрон "посмотреть, не пришёл ли поезд". Для этой цели как раз можно воспользоваться методом `available()`, который смотрит, есть ли доступные данные, которые можно считать из потока ввода или нет. Если данных нет, мы можем занять поток(thread) каким-нибудь другим делом и потом снова через некоторое время воспользоваться методом `available()` и считать данные тогда, когда они там будут.
В данном вопросе не стоит рассматривать взаимодействие потоков(thread), поскольку его тут нет. В многопоточной программе управление всегда будет передаваться разным потокам(thread), независимо от наличия/присутствия блокирующего метода в программе.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки нет, блокируется поток, а не процесс.

> А разве может этот текущий поток ...."

Представь у тебя пул потоков, разгребающих какую-то очередь задач. Один заблокирован в `read` - было бы удобно сказать этому потоку "пока тут read заблокирован, займись следующей задачей, а когда read разблокируется, вернись сюда и доделай", но блокирующее АПИ такого не позволяет.

В `java.nio` решён подкласс таких проблем - у тебя много сокетов, из которых надо читать данные. Вместо "один-поток-на-сокет" (*) используется неблокирующее чтение, которое позволяет потоку читать только из сокетов, где уже есть данные. Правда, взамен приходится менять подход работы с сокетами и использовать колбэки для обработки данных.

Более общее решение предлагают [Котлиновские корутины](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) и будущие "лёгкие потоки" в Яве, см. [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main)

Но надо понимать, что это "более общие", а не "абсолютные" решения на все случаи.

(*) Поток - недешёвый ресурс, под него сразу резервируется память при создании (в Яве это 512KB по-умолчанию), 1000 потоков == 512MB и это они ещё делать ничего не начали.

---

> Зачем может понадобиться выполнять такую проверку, чтобы избежать блокировки потока, ведь так управление другим потокам не передастся? В каких ситуациях это может понадобиться?

Если ты можешь дать потоку другую задачу, пока в сокете нет данных. В противном случае, конечно проще ждать.

> Правильно ли понимаю, что использование метода available() нужно как раз для таких ситуаций, когда есть несколько потоков и мы по какой-то причине не хотим передавать управление другим потокам, в случае чтения данных в текущем потоке, то есть хотим избежать блокировки текущего потока?

С другими потоками это никак не связано. Этот метод нужен только если мы не хотим блокировать текущие поток, потому что у нас есть чем его занять, пока нет данных.

---

Ну и общий вывод - неблокирующее чтение нужно только там, где каналов для чтения **десятки тысяч и более** - что-то типа серверной части мессенджеров (Telegram, What's up и т.п.). Если у тебя в программе несколько сокетов для чтения, то блокирующее чтение оптимально по соотношению `простота программы / используемые ресурсы`